# 500 server error codeigniter ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm getting a 500 server error within the console when the ajax script is executed, and I'm not sure as to why. If I change the code up a bit to implement mysqli functions, and run these on my local machine everything works just fine, but as soon as I try to get this to work with codeigniter, I get the 500 server error.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Phonecall extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        /*$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','MYDB');
        if (!$con) {
            die ('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }*/
        //$operatorId = $_SESSION['Oper']['OperatorID']; 
        //$sql = "SELECT phone_number FROM incoming_calls WHERE OperatorID='${operatorId}'";
        //$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT phone_number FROM MYDB.incoming_calls");// WHERE OperatorID='${operatorId}'");

        while ($row = $query->row_array()) {
            $number = $row['phone_number'];
        }

        /*$sql = "SELECT Username, UserID, Name
            FROM tblUsers 
            WHERE PhoneHome='999-999-9999' OR PhoneCell='999-999-9999' OR PhoneWork='999-999-9999'";
        */

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT Username, UserID, Name
            FROM MYDB.tblUsers 
            WHERE PhoneHome='999-999-9999' OR PhoneCell='999-999-9999' OR PhoneWork='999-999-9999'");

        while ($row = $query->row_array()) {
            $userArray[] = array("name" => $row['Name'], "username" => $row['Username'], "user_id" => $row['UserID']);
        }

        if (!empty($userArray)) {
            echo json_encode($userArray);
        }

        if (isset($_POST["drop"])) {
            $query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM MYDB.incoming_calls 
                WHERE phone_number = $number
                LIMIT 1");
            if (!$result) {
                die ('Could not drop row: ');
            }
        }

        $this->db->close();
    }
}

?>
```

Here is the ajax call that retrieves the information:

```
var user = new Array();
var user_id = new Array();
var name = new Array();

$.get(baseURL + 'phonecall/index', function(data) {//where baseURL is defined
    var loginInfo = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < loginInfo.length; ++i) {
        name[i] = loginInfo[i].name;
        user[i] = loginInfo[i].username;
        user_id[i] = loginInfo[i].user_id;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know as to why this would happen?

Comment: What if you call `baseURL + 'phonecall/index'` directly?

Comment: the log file would give you more info on this. Put the contents over here.

Comment: what will result in when you insert this code echo 'came here';die;    @(1) begin @(2) after query1 @(3) after query2 @(4) within if of json encode

Comment: If I put an echo "hello world"; at the top of the page, and go to the exact address I'll see "hello world", but something isn't right with my queries I'm assuming, any ideas?

Comment: i don't see `$this->load->database()` . have you initialized db ?

Comment: Okay I just initialized the db, I'm still receiving a 500 internal server error.

Comment: put your config.php `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;` && your database.php `$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;` for debugging

Comment: Check the network panel in inspect element when you make the AJAX call and check the response tab.  It's possible that you have CSRF protection enabled and the GET call is being denied.